# Why does middleware always fires?

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

After logging in, my app always goes to the dashboard as intended.

But even after clicking other directories, it always goes to the dashboard.

As I find out, the middleware named `RedirectIfAdmin` always fires.

I am using `hesto/multi-auth`.

**RedirectIfAdmin:**

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = 'admin')
{
   if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
      return redirect('myapp/dashboard');
   }

   return $next($request);
}
```

**On my admin route file:**

```
Route::group(['prefix' => '/myapp', 'as'=>'myapp.'], function () {
  Route::resources([
    'user' => '\App\Http\Controllers\UserController'
    ]);
});
```

So if I go to `myapp/user/` i am always redirected to `myapp/dashboard`.

I know that it was the code insde the `RedirectIfAdmin` that is firing when I go to `myapp/user` because if I change it to `myapp/dashboard123` then it goes to that url everytime i browse `myapp/user`, `myapp/user/create`, `myapp/user/123`, `myapp/user/123/edit`, etc.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While calling your `myapp/user/` try to call it with

```
project-url/admin/myapp/user
```

if you are calling with route then use like

```
admin.myapp.user
```

**Step 1:**

Inside your **RouteServiceProvider.php**

In that inside map function add this line:

```
$this->mapWebRoutes();
$this->mapAdminRoutes();
```

**Step 2:**

Inside RouteServiceProvider class add this function:

```
protected function mapAdminRoutes()
    {
        Route::group([
            'middleware' => ['web', 'admin', 'auth:admin'],
            'prefix' => 'admin',
            'as' => 'admin.',
            'namespace' => $this->namespace,
        ], function ($router) {
            require base_path('routes/admin.php');
        });
    }


protected function mapWebRoutes()
    {
        Route::middleware('web')
             ->namespace($this->namespace)
             ->group(base_path('routes/web.php'));
    }
```

**Step 3:**
Run below command in your project

```
php artisan optimize:clear
```

Comment: just tried, i got 404 error.

Comment: Please check updated answer do changes in RouteServiceProvider that will allow to call with specific auth.

Answer (score 0):

Check the `__construct()` on the user controller see if you referenced it there

Comment: thank you for your answer but i have no __construct() entry on my controller as I have already deleted it.

Comment: You deleted the construct or the middleware ?

Comment: i deleted the __construct() entry on the UserController

Comment: did you have a switch in your database to toggle between user and admin ? 
if so then this should go as follows 
`if ((Auth::guard($guard)->check()) && ($auth_user->type == 'admin')) {
      return redirect('myapp/dashboard');
   }` inside your redirectIfAdmin middleware

Comment: no, i only use one database sir.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237656/discussion-between-mostafa-hana-and-kapitan).